# What is a current status of spray-json version 2.0?

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json

I cloned [spray json](https://github.com/spray/spray-json.git) project, but see that Spray 2.0 branch `origin/feature/2.0.0` last commit on November 2012. Does it mean that spray-json 2.0.0 has been stopped? What it status/plans for today?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is of temporal nature and belongs in the respective project home forum / mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

The Spay project now is renamed or forming part in akka-http

[link to info](http://www.typesafe.com/blog/typesafe-gets-sprayed?_ga=1.65885102.1430087038.1441032815)

So The spray-json will be deprecated, and maybe will be added a project inside akka-http like this repo suggested

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-http-spray-json-experimental_2.10